# Fetch Each Row From a Column In MySQL And CURL On Each Domain And Change The Row With the New Fetched Domain

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, curl

I need to fetch each domain from a column and CURL on each domain in order to change that specific domains from the column with the right one.

Ex: example.test.com => check if the domain is accessible and find where it redirects => fetch the redirected domain => change the existent domain from the DB with the redirected domain

I have tried to do some pseudo-code but I still need some help as I don't have enough experience with PHP and MySQL in order to get this done:

```
// 1. Connect to DB

// 2. Interogate DB and get an array which contains every URLs

// 3. For each URL in the array call the getRedirectUrl($url) function with the URL as parameter

// 4. Save URL in the DB

$url = 'http://www.example.com';

function getRedirectedUrl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_exec($ch);

    $finalUrl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

    return rtrim($finalUrl,'/');
}


// Verify the response

var_dump(getRedirectedUrl($url));
```

If you can give me some advice I would really appreciate!

Comment: Can you please tell us the table name, and column name to retrieve ?

Comment: Table name: shops
Column: shop_url

Comment: just replace SELECT id, shop_url FROM shops AND UPDATE shops SET shop_url = :url WHERE id = :id. You must set param of your db in a another file in production

Answer (score 1):

Here are some advices to achieve your task. I'm using generic names for my examples.

Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php) to connect with your database:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$dbname;//$dbName is the name of your database
$user = 'root';
$pass = '123';//use your login information here
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user,$pass);
$query = "SELECT id, url FROM url_table";
$ps = $db->prepare($query);
$ps->execute();
$result = $ps->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);//this is a array with all your URLs to check
```

Iterate over the `$result` and use the same connection to Update your table

```
foreach ($result as $url) {
    $newURL = getRedirectedUrl($url['url']);
    $query = 'UPDATE url_table SET url = :url WHERE id=:id';
    $ps = $db->prepare($query);
    $ps->bindParam(':url', $newURL);
    $ps->binParam(':id', $url['id']);
    $ps->execute();
}
```